# How do I stop VirtualBox from running on localhost:8000?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, virtualbox

As in the title, simple (but without disabling VM machine). Looked everywhere but can't find an answer.

I have a Vbox Machine running Laravel but need Symfony to use 127.0.0.1:8000 instead. I just get one of my Laravel websites on that address, and they conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you restart pc or run Vbox, it will keep running again and again. **I recommend you to change prot which symfony runs**

In `httpd.conf` you can do this

```
# Be sure to only have this line once in your configuration
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8085

# This is the configuration for your project
Listen 127.0.0.1:8085

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8085>
  DocumentRoot "/home/sfproject/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/home/sfproject/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf /home/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/home/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Read these

1. [How to Use PHP's built-in Web Server](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html)
2. [Chapter 3 - Running Symfony](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/03-Running-Symfony)

> Not be the answer. Just an tip

Comment: Where can I locate this file on Windows? It seems that changing Vbox port (to 8001 for example, the other solution) just kills it and symfony does not run on 127.0.0.1:8000 when you do `php artisan server:run`.

Comment: `php artisan serve --port=xxxx` try this

Comment: I get a message that it is running but I can't access 127.0.0.1:8001 after `xxxx=8001`

Comment: port should same as `httpd.conf`  ex `Listen 127.0.0.1:8085` `127.0.0.1:XXXX` will work. or Control click on url appears on terminal

Comment: Oh right, I see. But where can I locate this file on Windows? Btw, I am running it all through homestead, and cd'ing into symfony folder and trying `[...] server:run`

Comment: in xamp `apache\conf\extra` and you will get `httpd-vhosts.conf`

Comment: I don't think I have apache installed, as I cannot find the file or directory anywhere. I have a Laravel Homestead vagrant box with VBox and Vagrant (which apparently has no apache installed). Symfony worked before this way (cd using commands into symfony directory and run server that way), and I could access localhost no problem, without Laravel interferring. Problem arose after updating to homestead-7.

Comment: sorry. i'm not good in windows. I use linux. So no idea with file paths

Comment: Ok. I should switch to Linux :) I also tried `php bin/console server:run 127.0.0.1:8001` but this also comes as connection reset in the browser. Clueless.

Comment: TIP:  check this path exist `bin/console`. Earlier I got this issue. **FYI**

Comment: It does because I get a confirmation that server runs, green message with [OK]. Yet browser is unable to connect.

Comment: ah so up to now im done then. ;) try some other answers. May you get some clue on this. Happy to help :)

Comment: Np. #soReadyToHelp ;)

Comment: Had to use `homestead.yaml` file to add new website with type of symfony there. `http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/homestead.html`. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Had to refresh cache too. The cache clearing wasn't clear in the docs, but all works.

Answer (score 1):

Just right click and select settings on vm. Go to network tab and choose your adapter. Click Advanced, you have to see 'Port Forwarding' there you can change ports.

[image: Port forwarding]

Comment: tcp8000 is host port 8000, is this the one? I only have one port directing to 127.0.0.1 which is 2222.